# AuthGuard always false in nebular

Tags: javascript, angular, nebular, ngx-admin

I use ngx admin to create admin panel that is use nebular, I follow this docs to add authGard:
[docs](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/protecting-application-routes#register-the-service)

and this to customize login:
[docs2](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/auth/custom-auth-components#login-component-extension)

all the things work true and I get success message :
[image: img]

but I get false in autogard:
[image: img2]

Code that I use:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthGuard,
  ],
  imports: [
    ***
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {
}

//**********

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private authService: NbAuthService, private router: Router) {
  }

  canActivate() {
    console.log(this.authService.isAuthenticated());
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .pipe(
        tap(authenticated => {
          if (!authenticated) {
            console.log(authenticated);
            this.router.navigate(['auth/login']);
          }
        }),
      );
  }
}

//**********

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module')
      .then(m => m.PagesModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: () => import('./auth/auth.module').then(m => m.NgxAuthModule),
  },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'pages', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'pages' },
];
```

Comment: Fisrt just try subscribe put breakpoint in and view result. If ok, the prom is in pipe area. Put breakpoint there and track down bug

Comment: @JohnPeters I'm new to angular, please explain more, I add breakpoint to login and it's successfully get data from server but after that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
Document said that response should be like this:

```
{
data: {
 token: 'some-jwt-token'
  } 
}
```

my response is:

```
{
data: {
  access_token: 'some-jwt-token'
  }
}
```

And in document write that we can change (token) to other things like this:

```
 token: {
           key: 'access_token', // this parameter tells where to look for the token
         }
```

But it's not true and we should use this in NbAuthModule.forRoot:

```
 token: {
           key: 'data.access_token',
         }
```